# Abdera parser: how to acess element with different namespaces

Tags: apache-abdera

Let's say I have an Atom entry like this:

```
<entry xmlns:custom="http://custom.xsd">
   <title>test</title>
   <custom:solution>42</custom:solution>
</entry>
```

If I load the entry into Apache Abdera, I get a nice `org.apache.abdera.model.Entry` instance. And I can now conveniently access all standard Atom elements with getters.

But how would I read the value `42` from the `custom:solution` element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
for (Element element : (List<Element>)entry.getExtensions(" <UrI for custom namespace>")) {
    System.out.println(element.getText());// gives you 42
}
```